# Is it possible to stop a running function (Not just clear the timeout before starts executing)?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I wrote a code, it does not stop the function, but is there such kind of way to do it? Or maybe there is a better way...

```
let stopper = false;

const toBeLowPriority = () => {
    for(let i = 0; i < Math.pow(10, 9); i += 1) {
        if(stopper) {
            console.log("for loop stopped");
            return
        }
        
        // do some stuff
        let k = Math.random();
        if (k === 0.5) {
            console.log(k);
        }
    }
    console.log("for loop done fully");
}


setTimeout(
    () => {
        stopper = true;
    }, 500
);


toBeLowPriority();
```

Comment: If it was an async loop you could.  Or if you run the code inside a webworker you could terminate the webworker.

Comment: no, since the earliest the setTimeout can run is after `toBeLowPriority` finishes

Comment: @Keith  How do you stop an asynchronous function?

Comment: @Yoel. Pretty much like how the OP tried to do it in his sync function.  The loop would require some form of async action to yield, stopper would then update, and break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

As your method `toBeLowPriority` must end before going into the setTimeout, that will never happen.

You can change the function to run only for several times then continue on a setImmediate. (or timeout)

let stopper = false;

```
const toBeLowPriority = (start=0, end = Math.pow(10, 9), checkEvery = 1000) => {
    for(let i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if(stopper) {
            console.log("for loop stopped at", i);
            return
        }
        // do some stuff
        let k = Math.random();
        if (k === 0.5) {
            console.log(k);
        }

        if( i >= checkEvery) {
            return setImmediate( () => toBeLowPriority(i, end, checkEvery) );
        }
    }
    console.log("for loop done fully");
}

toBeLowPriority();

setTimeout(
    () => {
        stopper = true;
    }, 500
);
```

And yes, now toBeLowPriority is no more synchrone.

Function that can be `stopped` must have been designed for such case. But as nearly everything in current JS is asynchronous, you will probably never get a such case in real life.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for some optimisation for my project with React.js.
I have a textarea in which a user can type/change text, and at every change, some function starts executing, but this function must execute only for the most updated text. If user types "abc" every 1 second for each letter, and if the function needs more than 1 second to finish, the textarea goes freezed/blocked because the function needs to finish. So, I thought, I could somehow stop the function when the user tries to make new changes in textarea, and then start the function again.

Comment: So in ReactJS, you have a change event handler on textarea that takes time... ok that sometimes happen... but it freezes the UI untill finished? What is it doing??

Comment: It analyzes the input text string, and on every change, new analyzation is needed. During the function execution a use cannot type anything in the textarea, because it is freezed during that time.